# How can I make the words in this button closer together?

Tags: html, css

I have this button here

[image: button]

But I would like to make the words very close together, pretty much right on top of eachother, with the print icon centered vertically to the right of them. I have been fiddling with the css and html forever now and I'm at a dead end. Here is what I have so far

```
<span id="print-report-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini">
    <span style="float:left;">
        <span style="display: block;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;">Huge</span>
        <span style="display: block;padding: 0px;">Report</span>
    </span>
    <span style="float: right;" style="padding: 0px;">
        <img src="images/icons/print.png" width="23" height="23" />
    </span>
</span>
```

update: the classes in the top level span are bootstrap button styles

Comment: Use line heights. Essentially, play the line height of the button  until you are comfortable with the distance between the words. Then set another line height on your image span (inline-block) to control it's vertical position separately from the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

play with the `line-height` property of the button.

For example:

```
#print-report-button {
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Although some of the other answers offer more in depth solution and general design advice, I am accepting this one because it is the most simple and works perfectly with my existing code. Ended up setting it to 12px. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make the image a background image instead, then you can use the [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) property to adjust the spacing. It's good practice to place images that are part of the UX in stylesheets, rather than HTML

Answer (score 2):

`flex` on the parent with `align-items: center` to center vertically, then alter the line-height to get the text to be tighter. I also put your text in a single element.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span id="print-report-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" style="display: inline-flex; align-items:center;">
    <span>
        <span style="display: block;padding: 0px;margin: 0px; line-height:1;">Huge <br> Report</span>
    </span>
    <span style="padding: 0px;">
        <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" width="23" height="23" />
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try negative top margin:

```
<span id="print-report-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini">
    <span style="float:left;">
        <span style="display: block;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;">Huge</span>
        <span style="display: block;padding: 0px;margin: -10px 0 0 0;">Report</span>
    </span>
    <span style="float: right;" style="padding: 0px;">
        <img src="images/icons/print.png" width="23" height="23" />
    </span>
</span>
```